# Scala for comprehension returns Option[List[T]]]; want List[Value]

Tags: scala, functional-programming, option-type, for-comprehension

I'm pretty new to Scala and am having some difficulty figuring out exactly how to extract form an `Option`

I have code that does:

```
getResult( name, age, id).map(response =>
  for {
    accounts <- response._id_list // response.account_id_list is an Option[String]
    ageList <- response.age_list // response.details is an Option[Details]
  } yield {
      accounts.split(" ").map(accountID =>  Account(
        accountID = accountID,
      ))
  }
)
```

This returns `Option[List[Account]]` but I just want to return a `List[Account]`. I know that the reason for this is because the for comprehension is really some syntactic sugar covering some `flatMaps` and `maps` but I can't figure out how to return the contents of the `Option`. I don't want to use `Option.get` because I've read that's terrible practice (as it essentially nullifies the whole point of the `Option`. So, how else can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a `.getOrElse(List.empty)`

Comment: Well that was rather simple. Thanks!